# SQL Server create table error - may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create this activity table:

```
CREATE TABLE activity 
(
    activity_id int,
    description varchar(300),
    start_date date,
    due_date date,
    plannes_price float,
    hours_worked int,
    billing_rate float,
    actual_price float,
    status varchar(50),
    employee_id int,
    date_completed date,
    service_id int,

    CONSTRAINT pk_activityId PRIMARY KEY (activity_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_act_emp_id FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) 
         REFERENCES employee(employee_id) 
         ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_act_ser_id FOREIGN KEY (service_id) 
         REFERENCES service(service_id) 
         ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

but I get this error:

> Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 114
>   Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'fk_act_ser_id' on table 'activity' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 114
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

If I set `fk_act_ser_id` constraint `UPDATE NO ACTION` then the code will run with no errors. But I want to set it is UPDATE CASCADE.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: We're going to have to see the `service` table's DDL as well.

Comment: *Side note:* please do **NOT** use  `float` (nor `real` or `double`) for price or rate information - those types are *notoriously* inaccurate and tend to fall victim to rounding errors. Use `decimal(p,s)` for **all** money-related values!

Comment: oh ok.. thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about the tables that aren't shown here. There are multiple ways to delete an `activity` - and one of those ways has two paths to `activity`. For example if a `service` can result in the deletion of an `employee` (or an `employee` deletion can delete a `service`)...or some other delete path. You can only have one delete/update path to any table from a given starting table.